# Why is the wood grain texture I applied to my model not showing?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I am trying to apply a wood grain type of effect to a model, I set up all the nodes and everything yet it won't show properly. How would I apply the texture?

[image: The texture]

[image: The model]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your mesh UV unwrapped?

Comment: No it's not UV unwrapped, would i need to make the UV map and use an image as a base for the texture?

Comment: You need to unwrap the mesh to apply an image texture to it.

Comment: Is your wood grain procedural or an image?  If it is procedural just change the mapping coordinates to *generated*.

Comment: I UV Unwrapped it and tweaked some of the sizes of the textures and it now is very close to the desired effect

Comment: Is is a procedural texture?

Comment: yes it's a procedural texture

Comment: It would appear that the tex *does* show in the render veiw.

Answer (score 1):

To get your procedural texture to show up in the material, go into the textures context tab, and in the mapping panel, change "co-ordinates" to generated, then, in the influence panel, under "diffuse", put a check beside color. Areas to be changed in orange boxes shown:

[image: Wood desk].